# Codeigniter Radio Button Logic

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter to give logic on Radio buttons true and false. but they are both getting the same value, I know this is because of the same name in view but how to change it as i am beginner to codeigniter and PHP.

My View:

```
<tr>
  <th>Host</th>
  <th width="10%">
    <label for="True">True</label>
  </th>
  <th width="10%">
    <label for="False">False<Label>
  </th>
</tr>`
<tr>
  <td>
    <?=$host2; ?>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="radio" name="Expired" value="true" id="" onclick="" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="radio" name="Expired" value="false" id="" onclick="" />
  </td>
```

My Controller:

```
$Expired = $this->CI->input->post('Expired');
```

Answer (score 0):

as i am not allowed to comment...

you can use.. value as yes and no. and then :

`$Expired = $this->CI->input->post('Expired') == "yes" ? true : false;`

hope this helps

Comment: i have a solution value which is i am posting in view by the controller, $this->sol returns true or false depends on the condition, i will try this lets c :)

Comment: if its solve your issues, please mark it as answer :)